# Is it possible to track the start time of a celery task?

Tags: python, flask, celery

I am trying to get the timestamp of when a particular task started in Celery. Is this possible? I have tried below but could not get it to work. I am using Celery 3.0.19 with mongodb as the broker in flask.

```
class GenericTask(Task):
    abstract = True
    startTime = unicode(datetime.datetime.now())


@celery.task(name="tasks.create_provider", base=GenericTask)
def create_provider(name):
    with app.test_request_context():
        Provider.create(name=name)
```

Then later..

```
async = create_provider.apply_async((name,), startTime=unicode(datetime.datetime.now()))

task = {'id': async.task_id,
        'operation': 'operation',
        'status': async.status,
        'startTime': async.startTime,
        'expiryTime': 'expiryTime'}
```

Answer (score 2):

Tasks can be tracked with a 'task-sent' event before they are consumed by a worker. Just append to your celery config:

```
CELERY_SEND_TASK_SENT_EVENT = True
```

Celerymon or celery flower should show the 'task-sent' event with timestamp.